# Twitter does not provide thumbnail tag from copied twitter link

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, frontend, thumbnails

Please help me with my issue. I've faced with problem when copied links from twitter app do not contain info about thumbnails (meta tags twitter:image or og:image) anymore. I am using OpenGraph protocol to get specific tags from these twitters links. A couple of weeks ago there were the thumbnails and they worked perfectly fine. How can I get this thumbnail from the copied twitter link using OpenGraph?

Here is the tags that are only exist in copied twitter link:

https://twitter.com/GoNOMAD/status/1261244110578618369?s=20

"fb:app_id" content="2231777543" and "og:site_name" content="Twitter"

Comment: At the moment the new Twitter design does not provide these tags, but they should be back in the future. See https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-removed-opengraph-tags-from-server-rendered-tweet-page/138473/2?u=andypiper

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: @AndyPiper, any news about working thumbnails guys?

Comment: There's no schedule for this unfortunately - but it is a known issue that we're working to address in the future.